# How can I convert an IP address into an integer with Lua?

Tags: string, lua, integer, ip

In Lua how would I go about converting a string containing an IP address into an integer?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

IPv4 I assume? and how do you want it as an integer?
maybe:

```
local str = "127.0.0.1"
local o1,o2,o3,o4 = str:match("(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)%.(%d%d?%d?)" )
local num = 2^24*o1 + 2^16*o2 + 2^8*o3 + o4
```

Answer (score 0):

Other approach could be:

```
local addr = "127.0.0.1"
local num = 0
addr:gsub("%d+", function(s) num = num * 256 + tonumber(s) end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am providing two solutions.

- **Solution 1**: without Lua Bit Operations. It is slow but no need of any external lua library and .so or .dll files.
- **Solution 2**: Performance is very good when you are calling those function very frequently. Performing operations on numbers at bit level is very very fast.

Solution 1:

```
function ip2dec(ip) local i, dec = 3, 0; for d in string.gmatch(ip, "%d+") do dec = dec + 2 ^ (8 * i) * d; i = i - 1 end; return dec end

function dec2ip(decip) local divisor, quotient, ip; for i = 3, 0, -1 do divisor = 2 ^ (i * 8); quotient, decip = math.floor(decip / divisor), math.fmod(decip, divisor); if nil == ip then ip = quotient else ip = ip .. "." .. quotient end end return ip end
```

Solution 2:

http://bitop.luajit.org/install.html

http://bitop.luajit.org/download.html

https://github.com/fengpeiyuan/ipconv

```
package.path  = package.path  .. ";/home/balaji/lualib/bitopt.lua"

package.cpath = package.cpath .. ";/home/balaji/lualib/bit.so"

local bit = require("bitopt")

function dec2ip(dec) return bit:band(bit:rshift(dec, 24), 0xFF) .. "." .. bit:band(bit:rshift(dec, 16), 0xFF) .. "." .. bit:band(bit:rshift(dec, 8), 0xFF) .. "." .. bit:band(dec, 0xFF) end

function ip2dec(ip) local dec = 0; for d in string.gmatch(ip, "%d+") do dec = d + bit:lshift(dec, 8) end; return dec end
```